# meteor iron:router Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I found out iron:router is causing error.  Using dburles:google-maps  and iron:router packages to make this code work. my code as below:
template.js:

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('whatisHappening')
});
}
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Meteor.startup(function () {
    GoogleMaps.load({v: '3', libraries: 'places'});
});
Template.whatisHappening.helpers({
    mapOptions: function () {
        if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
            var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{types: ['geocode']});
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                console.log(autocomplete.getPlace())
            });
        }
    }
});
}
```

layout.html

```
<template name="layout">
<a href="/">address search</a> |
    <a href="/x">some other page</a>
{{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="whatisHappening">
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete" placeholder="some address" size="50">
    {{mapOptions}}
</template>
```

if I don't use this iron:router it doesn't throw any error, it works perfectly.   is this kind of bug or do I need to improve my coding?

and how can I spot this kind of errors caused by packages?, it wasted my whole day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrapped with autorun which reactively updates the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a helper for this. When running JS in the middle of some HTML, you can never be sure what has been rendered and what not. I'd use the `onRendered` hook.

```
Template.whatisHappening.onRendered(function () {
  if (!GoogleMaps.loaded()) return false;
  var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{types: ['geocode']});
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    console.log(autocomplete.getPlace())
  });
});
```

Comment: i have tried onRendered and onCreated. that didn't help. please try to refresh the page, when page is refreshed, page is not rendered/created again somehow. it might be iron:router bug.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest coding defensively, your helper may be called multiple times, an early call is coming in before your DOM has rendered all its elements.

```
Template.whatisHappening.helpers({
  mapOptions: function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded() && input ) {
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{types: ['geocode']});
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        console.log(autocomplete.getPlace())
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: it is definitely something to do with iron-router with checking if the field exist, it will void whole function below. with page refresh will work. I have tried all. :(